# Swift Dictionary [String:String] to NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary, sprite-kit, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to create and assign a Swift `Dictionary` of type `[String : String]` at the `SKSpriteNode` property `userData` which requires an `NSMutableDictionary`. When I try this I get the error:

```
'[String : String]' is not convertible to 'NSMutableDictionary'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
    // USER DATA
    var dictionary: [String : String] = Dictionary()
    dictionary["Orbit"] = orbit
    dictionary["Zone"] = zone
    dictionary["Impact"] = impact
    var foundationDictionary = dictionary as NSMutableDictionary
    neoSprite.userData = foundationDictionary
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There’s no built-in cast for this.  But instead you can use `NSMutableDictionary`’s initializer that takes a dictionary:

```
var foundationDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: dictionary)
```

Comment: Much appreciated everyone, Thank you Airspeed, much simpler than I was expecting.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative answer to the answers above is to cast your dictionary to NSDictionary create a mutable copy of it and cast it to NSMutableDictionary. Too complicated, right ? Therefore I recommend creating new NSMutableDictionary from Dictionary this is just an alternative

```
var foundationDictionary = (dictionary as NSDictionary).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to replace this line:

```
var foundationDictionary = dictionary as NSMutableDictionary
```

With this code:

```
var foundationDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: dictionary)
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries

Create immutable dictionary

```
let dictionary = ["Item 1": "description", "Item 2": "description"]
```

Create mutable dictionary

```
var dictionary = ["Item 1": "description", "Item 2": "description"]
```

Append new pair to dictionary

```
dictionary["Item 3"] = "description"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am so late in answering this question and one answer is already accepted, but still to help someone.

Sometime converting swift dictionary ([String : String] or [AnyHashable : String] or any other) to Objective-C NSMutableDictionary, if there are some nested objects like array or dictionaries within that will not get mutable as so when updating the values will get error of `[NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance`

To prevent this error one can convert the object in objective-c class.

In my case I am converting a JSON string into swift dictionary and passing it to objective c class by casting it in NSMutableDictionary as per my core requirement. This gives me an above error when I try to update the NSMutableDictionary in Objective C class.

After surfing and trying much I found that if I try to convert my JSON string in NSMutableDictionary in Objective-C class itself than it worked for me.

So try this: In aVC.swift

```
let Str: String = nsmanagedobject.value(forKey: "<key>") as? String {
     if let mutableDict: NSMutableDictionary = ApplicationData.convertJsonObject(fromJsonString: Str) as? NSMutableDictionary {
          ......
          <Your code to pass NSMutableDictionary to respected Objective-C class>
          ......
     }
```

ApplicationData.h

```
+ (NSObject *)convertJsonObjectFromJsonString:(NSString *)jsonString;
```

ApplicationData.m

```
+ (NSObject *)convertJsonObjectFromJsonString:(NSString *)jsonString {
    NSObject *jsonObject = nil;
    if ([jsonString length] > 0) {
        NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if (jsonData) {
            jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"jsonObject: %@",jsonObject);
    return jsonObject;
}
```

I hope this will help someone and save some time.